# C-planes and associated valuations in the paper of James Ax titled "On Schanuel's conjecture"

Tags: number-theory, function-fields, differential-algebra

I am currently trying to understand Proposition 2. (page 257 of the JSTOR version) in the above cited paper of Ax. It says the following:

Let $F\supseteq C \supseteq \mathbb{Q}$ be a tower of fields. Then the canonical map
$$
C\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}dF/F \longrightarrow \Omega_{F/C}/dF
$$
is injective.

In the proof, it is said that one can assume $F$ has finite transcendence degree over $C$ and the general case can be reduced to the case of transcendence degree $1$. Furthermore, $C$ may be assumed to be relatively algebraically closed in $F$ so that $F=C(T)$ for some $T$ transcendental over $C$.

Now, the part I have trouble figuring out is the following. In the middle of the proof, it is stated:

Thus for each $C$-plane $p$ of $F$ there is a well defined valuation
$$ 
\mathrm{ord}_p: F\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \cup \{\infty\}
$$
and a $C$-linear map
$$
\mathrm{res}_p: \Omega_{F/C} \longrightarrow C.
$$

My questions are:

1. What is a $C$-plane in this context?
2. How does one define valuations associated to such $C$-planes?
3. What is the map $\mathrm{res}_p$?

Comment: I think it is $C$-[place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)) not $C$-plane. So it means a (discrete) valuation on $F$ which is trivial  on $C$. If $F=C(T)$ then there is one per monic irreducible polynomial $\in C[T]$ plus one for $T^{-1}$.

Comment: Concretely for $f\in C[T]$ irreducible, take a root $a\in \overline{C}$, there is the natural discrete valuation $v((T-a)^j)=j$ on $C(a)[T-a]$ which extends to the fraction field $C(a)(T)$ and which restricts to $C(T)$.

Comment: Oh my god! It makes complete sense. It did not occur to me that it might have been a typo. Thank you @reuns .